# (Forecasting) Calculating the balance in the future

Tags: sql, sql-server

My product team has asked if I could create a very crude forecasting data table for them to work with.  I have a pretty good idea on a lot of the steps I need to take, but I am stuck on figuring how to to calculate the Inventory Quantity for tomorrow, the next day, etc.

In my database, I am able to see our current quantity on hand.  I would call that starting balance (for today).  I am then going to create an average usage field and that will be my estimated daily sales.  I will then take the starting balance - estimated daily sales = ending balance.  I can do that for today, my question is how do I roll that formula forward for the next 120 days

Comment: `[estimated daily sales] *  [number of days]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE to generate number from `0` to `120` and then calculate the day and balance with them.

```
DECLARE @estimated_daily_sales integer = 2;
DECLARE @starting_balance integer = 12345;

WITH
cte AS
(
SELECT 0 i 
UNION ALL
SELECT i + 1 i
       FROM cte
       WHERE i + 1 <= 120
)
SELECT dateadd(day, i, convert(date, getdate())) day,
       @starting_balance - i * @estimated_daily_sales balance
       FROM cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 120);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=d0f767ad2a14f75b6fb6f292320aa6d0)

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try.  With this approach, would I be able to change the estimated_daily_sales integer based upon the date?  For example, for the current month our ADU might be 500.  But for next month (dates in November) sales overall decrease by 5%, so our ADU needs to be 475.

Comment: @MattC: If you move the calculation into the recursive CTE you can use a `CASE` there, that returns different values depending on the month (or something else).

Comment: @sticky_bit  I've been doing some work on this and running into a couple of snags.  My first day does not appear to have the correct beginning balance or ending balance compared to the days afterwards.  I'm not sure I am displaying "starting balance" correctly?  Also I am trying to add in my expect PO arrivals on the particular days and those values do not extend beyond the day that they arrive.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=ef43b03c2812ae160ad23e39b7dd6105